# Unbound Variables in Scheme

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

```
(define input (read-line))
(define lngth (string-length input))
(define first-char (string-ref input 0))
(define test-num 
  (string->number 
   (substring input 0 (- (string-search-forward " " input) 1))))
(define end (string-search-forward ")" input))
(define beginning (string-search-backward "(" input))
(define operation (string (substring input beginning (+ end 1))))
(define space1 (string-search-forward " " operation))
(define space2 (string-search-backward " " operation))
(define n1 (string->number (substring operation 1 space1)))
(define n2 (string->number (substring operation (+ space1 1) space2)))
(define result (1))
(define operator (substring operation (+ space2 1) end))

(if (or (equal? first-char #\() (number? test-num))
    (display "yay")
    (display "ERROR"))
```

I'm using this with MIT/GNU Scheme implementation, which lets me run this code and responds correctly. My problem though is that once user data is put into the function it doesn't bind any sort of information to the variables. I.E. after putting in data and trying to access any of the parameters I get the following:

```
1 ]=> (display input)
;Unbound variable : input
```

Comment: How are you 'running' the code?  Most likely you are running it in a way the evaluates the forms in one environment and then when you got to access the variables you can't find them in your evaluation environment.

Comment: I'm saving it in a text file as a .scm and then opening it directly with the MIT/GNU Scheme interpreter.

Comment: You say `(load file.scm)` and then the loading waits for you to type something (because you called `read-line`)?  Or does something else happen?

Comment: It waits for me to type something, and then depending on what I type it displays either option in the included if. The problem rises when, after doing the typing, I try to call the value of any of the defined variables. That's when I get the unbound variable message.

Comment: I just tested it; it works for me.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, works for me:

```
$ mit-scheme 
MIT/GNU Scheme running under MacOSX
Type `^C' (control-C) followed by `H' to obtain information about interrupts.

Copyright (C) 2011 Massachusetts Institute of Technology
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY
or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Image saved on Tuesday November 8, 2011 at 10:45:46 PM
  Release 9.1.1 || Microcode 15.3 || Runtime 15.7 || SF 4.41 || LIAR/x86-64 4.118 || Edwin 3.116

1 ]=> (load "bar.scm")

;Loading "bar.scm"...(a b c)           ;; (define input (read-line))
 done
;Value: len

1 ]=> input                            ;; 'input' is bound

;Value 13: "(a b c)"

1 ]=> ^D
End of input stream reached.
Moriturus te saluto.
```

Comment: That's strange. I'll try going on another computer or something along those lines. Thanks very much for your help anyway.